# How to rotate application secret key using azure policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We are currently looking for solutions to rotate secret key(s) create for our azure applications annually.  We have explored key vault but did not find a way to rotate keys associated with application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to rotate application secret key using azure policy.

Your applications no longer need to persist your keys or secrets, but can request them from the vault as needed. A key vault allows you to update keys and secrets without affecting the behavior of your application, which opens up a breadth of possibilities for your key and secret management.

Please go through the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/key-rotation-log-monitoring)

Answer (score 0):

You could write a powershell script to create new application keys, then update secrets in keyvault, then using raghavendra's article access the keys in keyvault using the service principal of the application.

take a look at the cmdlet `new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadapplicationpasswordcredential?view=azureadps-2.0

then you could put that script in a azure automate or azure function app or something and set it to run say once a year.